# How can I search for specific phrases on my site as if I were not me?

Tags: google-search

In the body of my page is this line:

"counterfeit bull-fiddle saliva dancer".

Running in incognito mode, if I google search for it, it finds my page, even without the quotes. But I'm wondering if it just finds it because IT'S ME, given my history of going to that site. I want to fairly test the efficacy of certain phrases, whether in the body, or meta. Google console probably has ways to do it, but THERE'S NO TEST LIKE THE REAL THING.

How can I do this without using someone else's computer & IP addr ?

Comment: One way is to post a question here and someone will try that search and see that it does lead back to your page :o)  But you can't get away with doing that every time you want it tested.   FWIW Incognito mode does not hide your IP address.  It only stops history, browsing info and cookies being saved.

Comment: @Steve *...and someone will try that search...* So true!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this without using someone else's computer & IP addr ?

This is rather impossible unless the search engine can customize search results based on stored cookies in the browser or based on the browser itself. The reason is because the internet protocol today is TCP/IP and each packet that a computer sends to the world always contains the source IP address as well as a destination IP address. Web server Software (example: apache) can retrieve the IP address of a guest computer and allow a website to display different data based on the IP address. For example, a web server can be configured to print out "access denied" messages to a block of IP addresses.

Now if you want to try your luck, then put in your search query for your site in a web browser, see the results, then clear all cookies in the browser and try the same search again. Do the same with several different web browsers and see what you get.

Consider using other search engines such as Bing. I remembered that google recently manipulated search results so that certain pages came first before others and the european union apparently sued google and won. See: http://thehackernews.com/2017/06/google-search-antitrust-fine.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use another browser, said safari and use google.com to search for your group of keywords.

I would recommend Tor browser it's free and it claims that does respects your privacy. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31589/why-is-tor-safer-than-a-proxy) will provide you with more information about it.

You could also use a VPN or proxy server that will help you to connect using different locations, there are free ones but definitely you will need to pay to get a decent service.

Now, it is important to point out that your phrase is not common and if you use that particular exact phrase your website is most likely to be the one to come out first in the search results, try using one of your headings or more common phrases in your content.

If you want to track a keyword's rankings try a tool to track its performance, most of these tools offer a free tier that you can use for this purpose. Good luck! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this without using someone else's computer & IP addr ?

You can simply do that by asking your friend to help. They just enter the phases on GG search and then capture the result for you.

Another way is using VPS (if you have). Just login in your VPS server placed at another country and do a search to see the result.